# Changing RichTextBox to a Label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I am using a rich text box as a label for my application. The text box is read-only but its content can be selected. How can I make users can't select text in the rich text box while it is read-only?

When I disable the control can't select text but I loose the colors, because they become grey (disabled). How can I disable text selection without disabling the rich text box control?

FYI: I am using a rich text box as a label because, I need to change the fore color to red for one word in the string which needs to be shown to the user. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926912/changing-string-colour/9927218#9927218) SO article and following method to do it.

```
string word = "red";
int start = richTextBox1.Find(word);
if (start >= 0) {
    richTextBox1.Select(start, word.Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```

**EDIT:** BTW It's C# WinForm

Comment: What difference does it make if the text is selectable? They can't edit it or delete it, so there are no possible negative side effects.

Comment: @CodyGray You're correct. But, it's appearance should be as a label. That's why I'm trying to do so.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805545/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-a-disabled-control)

Comment: By the way, is this WinForms or WPF? You should tag it as such to avoid the ambiguity (as both have a `RichTextBox`).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I've edited it. Its Winform

Comment: Accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805545/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-a-disabled-control works great. Thanks @Damith.

Answer (score 2):

Simply handle the selection, and restore it to "nothing":

```
// so you have colour (set via the Designer)
richTextBox.Enabled = true;

// so users cannot change the contents (set via the Designer)
richTextBox.ReadOnly = true;

// allow users to select the text, but override what they do, IF they select the text (set via the Designer)
richTextBox.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox_SelectionChanged);

// If the user selects text, then de-select it
private void richTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Move the cursor to the end
    if (this.richTextBox.SelectionStart != this.richTextBox.TextLength)
    {
        this.richTextBox.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox.TextLength;
    }
}
```

Taken from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/d1132ee5-acad-49f3-ae93-19d386fe2d12/

(By the way, a little bit [of searching](http://www.google.com/search?q=richtextbox%20disable%20selection) goes a long way.)

Comment: Does this have an ugly partial-selection flicker whenever the user goes to select something?

Comment: @CodyGray I hadn't tested it yet, but I suspect that it does. But if the OP wants to use a control for something it wasn't designed for, I suppose you have to accept less-than-perfect behavior.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I referred it. And I also used the accepted answer in the MSDN article. But the back color remain same. Grey disabled.

Comment: @CodyGray (unrelated): [someone needs your help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15795957/643085)